# Upgrade vs dist-upgrade vs apt-get install linux-headers-generic

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, kernel

I am running Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS

I wanted to know the difference between the three commands here

```
apt-get upgrade
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get install linux-headers-generic-xxx
```

My goal is to get the latest libraries for each package that I have on my server. 
Update:

We were running 12.04 on all our VMS, some are stuck at 12.04.3 and I would like to bring those to 12.04.5 from the command line without breaking anything.

On another note, I know that 14.04 is the latest one, and I should run a do-release-upgrade. But will it break things?

Comment: Using Ubuntu 12.04 will definitevly not get you the "latest", what exactly do you need it to be the "latest".

Comment: updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**apt-get**

From [Debian](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/apt-guide/ch2.en.html):

> **upgrade**
>
> Upgrade will attempt to gently upgrade the whole system. Upgrade will
>   never install a new package or remove an existing package, nor will it
>   ever upgrade a package that might cause some other package to break.
>   This can be used daily to relatively safely upgrade the system.
>   Upgrade will list all of the packages that it could not upgrade, this
>   usually means that they depend on new packages or conflict with some
>   other package. dselect or apt-get install can be used to force these
>   packages to install.
>
> **install**
>
> Install is used to install packages by name. The package is
>   automatically fetched and installed. This can be useful if you already
>   know the name of the package to install and do not want to go into a
>   GUI to select it. Any number of packages may be passed to install,
>   they will all be fetched. Install automatically attempts to resolve
>   dependency problems with the listed packages and will print a summary
>   and ask for confirmation if anything other than its arguments are
>   changed.
>
> **dist-upgrade**
>
> Dist-upgrade is a complete upgrader designed to simplify upgrading
>   between releases of Debian. It uses a sophisticated algorithm to
>   determine the best set of packages to install, upgrade and remove to
>   get as much of the system to the newest release. In some situations it
>   may be desired to use dist-upgrade rather than spend the time manually
>   resolving dependencies in dselect. Once dist-upgrade has completed
>   then dselect can be used to install any packages that may have been
>   left out.
>
> It is important to closely look at what dist-upgrade is going to do,
>   its decisions may sometimes be quite surprising.

---

To get the latest updates of the installed packages do:

```
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade
```

---

The command

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic-xxx
```

will install the specific kernel for the version you specify in place of `xxx`